# The type or namespace name "MonoBehavior" can't be found,Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've imported the "Standard Assets" from AssetsStore, and set a Scene containing an Island with water surrounding it. Link to asset pack -> https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2018-4-32351

Still, I get a compiler error("Type or namespace MonoBehavior could not be found") when trying to compile WaterBase.cs. Here's the script:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityStandardAssets.Water
{
    public enum WaterQuality
    {
        High = 2,
        Medium = 1,
        Low = 0,
    }

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class WaterBase : MonoBehavior
    {
        public Material sharedMaterial;
        public WaterQuality waterQuality = WaterQuality.High;
        public bool edgeBlend = true;


        public void UpdateShader()
        {
            if (waterQuality > WaterQuality.Medium)
            {
                sharedMaterial.shader.maximumLOD = 501;
            }
            else if (waterQuality > WaterQuality.Low)
            {
                sharedMaterial.shader.maximumLOD = 301;
            }
            else
            {
                sharedMaterial.shader.maximumLOD = 201;
            }

            // If the system does not support depth textures (ie. NaCl), turn off edge bleeding,
            // as the shader will render everything as transparent if the depth texture is not valid.
            if (!SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.Depth))
            {
                edgeBlend = false;
            }

            if (edgeBlend)
            {
                Shader.EnableKeyword("WATER_EDGEBLEND_ON");
                Shader.DisableKeyword("WATER_EDGEBLEND_OFF");
                // just to make sure (some peeps might forget to add a water tile to the patches)
                if (Camera.main)
                {
                    Camera.main.depthTextureMode |= DepthTextureMode.Depth;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Shader.EnableKeyword("WATER_EDGEBLEND_OFF");
                Shader.DisableKeyword("WATER_EDGEBLEND_ON");
            }
        }


        public void WaterTileBeingRendered(Transform tr, Camera currentCam)
        {
            if (currentCam && edgeBlend)
            {
                currentCam.depthTextureMode |= DepthTextureMode.Depth;
            }
        }


        public void Update()
        {
            if (sharedMaterial)
            {
                UpdateShader();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Has anyone else had this problem??

Comment: are you indeed missing a `{` after `namespace UnityStandardAssets.Water` like you show here ?

Comment: No ... Just went wrong when I pasted the code here. Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit the post.

Comment: ah ... and it should be `MonoBehaviour` instead of `MonoBehavior`

Comment: The `WaterBase` class is trying to inherit from `MonoBehavior` (US spelling), when it should be `MonoBehaviour` (British form of behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

To close the topic, the MonoBehavior has incorrect spelling, it should be MonoBehaviour

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)